# Override event handler in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm developing a windows form application with c# and I want to know if it's possible in a method of the event click have 3 parameters something like this

`private void cedulaTextBox_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e, KeyEventArgs ke)`

Or all the time we need to declare our methods like this

`private void nombreTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

No. `EventHandler<T>` only has options for sender and one `EventArgs`. If you are writing your own event, why not roll your own `EventArgs`?

Answer (score 3):

Your event handler needs to match the event it is handling.  If you want to have one event handler that deals with multiple different types of events, just do a little refactoring...

```
private void cedulaTextBox_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sharedHandler( sender, null, e );
}

private void nombreTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  sharedHander( sender, e, null );
}

private void sharedHandler( object sender, EventArgs textChangedArgs, EventArgs clickedArgs )
{
  ...
}
```